# Can the image representing a rendering in Page Editor be customized?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

Can the image representing the rendering in Page Editor be customized?  I have been able to update the text below the image by changing the Display Name to "Call To Action"... was just wondering if I could update the image above the text with a snip from the comp instead of the little blue outlined box.

[image]

Sitecore 7 Update-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the image by editing the "Thumbnail" field on the Sublayout/Rendering. The field is hidden by default though, so you will need to check the "Standard Fields" checkbox on the "View" ribbon.

Comment: I didn't think to try the standard fields. I will try this now.